# Unable to start SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I've been trying to use Microsoft SQL Server but when I try to start SQL Server Reporting Services in the Configuration Manager it says "The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details.".

The server is through my school (and the class that the server is for has been over for a month) but I was still using it this past week. I'm pretty sure there hasn't been any updates to SQL on my computer.

I've tried a lot of solutions posted here and on Google but nothing has worked.

Here's the error log copied and pasted. I would've uploaded it as a file but I'm new to this site and it didn't look like you could do that.

```
<Header>
  <Product>Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 2015.0130.1601.05 ((SQL16_RTM).160429-2226)</Product>
  <Locale>English (United States)</Locale>
  <TimeZone>Eastern Daylight Time</TimeZone>
  <Path>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MS410\Reporting Services\Logfiles\ReportServerService__06_24_2018_11_43_13.log</Path>
  <SystemName>DESKTOP-OMJU94B</SystemName>
  <OSName>Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200</OSName>
  <OSVersion>6.2.9200</OSVersion>
  <ProcessID>1316</ProcessID>
  <Virtualization>None</Virtualization>
</Header>
<ProcessorArchitecture>AMD64</ProcessorArchitecture>
<ApplicationArchitecture>AMD64</ApplicationArchitecture>
rshost!rshost!31e8!06/24/2018-11:43:13:: i INFO: CLR runtime is initialized.
rshost!rshost!31e8!06/24/2018-11:43:13:: i INFO: Derived memory configuration based on physical memory as 12430260 KB
rshost!rshost!31e8!06/24/2018-11:43:13:: w WARN: Failed to initialize performance counters: 2. Possible setup issue.
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!31e8!06/24/2018-11:43:13:: i INFO: Entered managed ServiceMain in DefaultDomain.
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!31e8!06/24/2018-11:43:13:: i INFO: Attempting to start WebApp service: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MS410\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\..\..\RSWebApp\Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost.exe
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing ConnectionType to '0'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing SecureConnectionLevel to '0'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing DisableSecureFormsAuthenticationCookie to 'False'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing CleanupCycleMinutes to '10' minute(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing MaxActiveReqForOneUser to '20' requests(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing DatabaseQueryTimeout to '120' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing RunningRequestsScavengerCycle to '60' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing RunningRequestsDbCycle to '60' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing RunningRequestsAge to '30' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing MaxScheduleWait to '5' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing DisplayErrorLink to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing WebServiceUseFileShareStorage to 'False'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing WatsonFlags to '1064'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing WatsonDumpOnExceptions to 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.Modeling.InternalModelingException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing WatsonDumpExcludeIfContainsExceptions to 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException,System.Web.UI.ViewStateException,System.OutOfMemoryException,System.Web.HttpException,System.IO.IOException,System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException,System.AppDomainUnloadedException'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing AuthenticationTypes to '4'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel to 'Off'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario to 'Proxy'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing EnableAuthPersistence to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing IsSchedulingService to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing IsNotificationService to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing IsEventService to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing PollingInterval to '10' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing WindowsServiceUseFileShareStorage to 'False'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing MemorySafetyMargin to '80' percent as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing MemoryThreshold to '90' percent as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing RecycleTime to '720' minute(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing MaxAppDomainUnloadTime to '30' minute(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing MaxQueueThreads to '0' thread(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: w WARN: Initializing UrlRoot to default value of ''  because it was incorrectly specified in Configuration file as ''.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing IsWebServiceEnabled to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing IsReportManagerEnabled to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing MaxConnections to '2'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing Timeout to '10' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing AppID to '(Default)'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Initializing CacheLevel to 'Default'  as specified in Configuration file.
resourceutilities!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Reporting Services starting SKU: Developer
configmanager!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Using report server internal url http://localhost:80/ReportServer_MS410.
configmanager!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Using report server external url http://DESKTOP-OMJU94B:80/ReportServer_MS410.
configmanager!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Using url root http://DESKTOP-OMJU94B:80/ReportServer_MS410.
rshost!rshost!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Configuring maxPhysicalCpu=0, minLogicalCpu=0
rshost!rshost!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Logical processor per physical processor 4
rshost!rshost!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Logical processor per core 2
rshost!rshost!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Logical processor unlimited
rshost!rshost!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: i INFO: Maximum logical CPU is 4
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!1c88!06/24/2018-11:43:14:: e ERROR: Child Process Died. Restarting it. Check the log for further information: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MS410\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\..\..\RSWebApp\Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost.exe
library!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:29:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
servicecontroller!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:29:: e ERROR: Error initializing configuration from the database: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!1dfc!06/24/2018-11:43:29:: e ERROR: Appdomain:1 DefaultDomain failed to initialize. Error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.InternalGetValue(String name, Object defaultValue, Boolean doNotExpand, Boolean checkSecurity)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValue(String name)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceMonitor.GetData(String item)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetPerformanceData(String item)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CategoryExists(String machine, String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(String categoryName, String machineName)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.RSCounter.Init(String categoryName, String counterName, String instanceName, RSTrace tracer, Boolean resetCounter)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.PerformanceCounters.Init(Boolean resetCounters, String instanceName, RunningApplication runningApplication)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Globals.InitServerWithoutDumperInner(Boolean resetAllPerfCounters)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Globals.InitServer(Boolean resetAllPerfCounters)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ServiceAppDomainController.StartInternal(Object parentThread).
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!2dc!06/24/2018-11:43:29:: e ERROR: Windows service failed to start. Exception: System.Exception: Default appdomain failed to initialize.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ServiceAppDomainController.Start()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportService.OnStart(String[] args)
```

Comment: I suspect this is the problem: `The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing.` Is the SQL Server Data Engine running, and Is the ReportServer database still accessible by the service account?

Comment: Everything else on the Configuration Manager is running. I don't know if the ReportServer database is accessible. I also emailed my professor last night but haven't received a reply yet.

Comment: The ReportSever database doesn’t have much to do with the configuration manager (i assume you are referring to the reporting services configuration manager). That is part of the SQL Database Engine. The database server need to be running and the ReportServer database needs to be present. You can check the connection string in the SSRS Configuration Manager.

Comment: How do I check if the database server is running and if the Report Server database is present? And how do I where do I find the connection string?

Comment: YOu'll need to log onto the Database engine and see if the configured database exists. You can find out what server, and database, has been configured in the Reporting Services Configuration tool on the server.